# Is freopen() part of ansi c?

Tags: c, standards, ansi-c

I got an assignment in which I can use any method, as long as it is part of the ANSI - c standard. I want to use `freopen`, except I don't know if its part of the standard. I have looked at "The C programming language" book's list of methods and it doesn't seem to be there, but it was in C89 so I doubt it isn't in ANSI.

Comment: The `freopen` is definitelly part of the C89 standard.

Comment: cf. _Section 7.9.5.4 The freopen function_ in _ANSI/ISO 9899-1990_

Comment: And it still in C; C11 [§7.21.5.4 The `freopen` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4).

Comment: `freopen()` still in the current version of C: C17/18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freopen()` function [conforms to C89](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen).

And C89 is [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C).